# wp_register_script unable to link bootstrap JS

Tags: javascript

This is my function to load the bootstrap files.

```
function load_js()
{
    wp_register_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'jquery', false, true );     
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

I would expect this to route to:

http://site.test/wp-content/themes/themename/js/bootstrap.min.js

But instead it does:

http://site.test/wp-content/themes/themenamejs/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 2):

```
function load_js()
{
    wp_register_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true );     
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

Use with `array('jquery')` instead of `'jquery'`

Refference [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/).
It says: use array.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to change anything. When I look at the source the bootstrap css is still linked like: <script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.test/wp-content/themes/themenamejs/bootstrap.min.js?ver=5.3'></script>

Comment: It looks like true. Maybe you added any filter function?

Comment: Haven't added a filter function. I am loading the bootstrap css in a similar way and having no issues:     wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), false, 'all' ); 
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');